# How can I get my carousel to move to the previous item?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm following this carousel tutorial and got it to work, but I'm stuck trying to make the carousel go the opposite direction.

https://usefulangle.com/post/313/css-flex-order-carousel-infinite

This is what I have so far in js:

```
const FlexSliderNext = {
    // total no of items
    num_items: document.querySelectorAll(".slide_image").length,
    
    // position of current item in view
    current: 1,

    init: function() {
        // set CSS order of each item initially
        document.querySelectorAll(".slide_image").forEach(function(element, index) {
            element.style.order = index+1;
        });

        this.addEvents();
    },

    addEvents: function() {
        var that = this;
        
        // click on move item button
        document.querySelector("#move-button-next").addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.gotoNext();
        });

        // after each item slides in, slider container fires transitionend event
        document.querySelector("#slide").addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            this.changeOrderNext();
        });
    },

    changeOrderNext: function() {
        // change current position
        if(this.current == this.num_items)
            this.current = 1;
        else 
            this.current++;

        let order = 1;

        // change order from current position till last
        for(let i=this.current; i<=this.num_items; i++) {
            document.querySelector(".slide_image[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
            order++;
        }

        // change order from first position till current
        for(let i=1; i<this.current; i++) {
            document.querySelector(".slide_image[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
            order++;
        }

        // translate back to 0 from -100%
        // we don't need transitionend to fire for this translation, so remove transition CSS
        document.querySelector("#slide").classList.remove('slider-container-transition');
        document.querySelector("#slide").style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    },

    gotoNext: function() {
        // translate from 0 to -100% 
        // we need transitionend to fire for this translation, so add transition CSS
        document.querySelector("#slide").classList.add('slider-container-transition');
        document.querySelector("#slide").style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
    }
};


const FlexSliderPrev = {
    // total no of items
    num_items: document.querySelectorAll(".slide_image").length,
    
    // position of current item in view
    current: -1,

    init: function() {
        // set CSS order of each item initially
        document.querySelectorAll(".slide_image").forEach(function(element, index) {
            element.style.order = index-1;
        });

        this.addEvents();
    },

    addEvents: function() {
        var that = this;
        
        // click on move item button
        document.querySelector("#move-button-prev").addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.gotoPrev();
        });

        // after each item slides in, slider container fires transitionend event
        document.querySelector("#slide").addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            this.changeOrderPrev();
        });
    },

    changeOrderPrev: function() {
        // change current position
        if(this.current == this.num_items)
            this.current = 2;
        else 
            this.current--;

        let order = 2;

        // change order from current position till last
        for(let i=this.current; i>=this.num_items; i--) {
            document.querySelector(".slide_image[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
            order--;
        }

        // change order from first position till current
        for(let i=2; i>this.current; i--) {
            document.querySelector(".slide_image[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
            order--;
        }

        // translate back to 0 from 100%
        // we don't need transitionend to fire for this translation, so remove transition CSS
        document.querySelector("#slide").classList.remove('slider-container-transition');
        document.querySelector("#slide").style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    },

    gotoPrev: function() {
        // translate from 0 to -100% 
        // we need transitionend to fire for this translation, so add transition CSS
        document.querySelector("#slide").classList.add('slider-container-transition');
        document.querySelector("#slide").style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
    }
};

FlexSliderPrev.init();
FlexSliderNext.init();`
```

I know it's probably not the most efficient way, but I tried to make the exact copy of the original "FlexSliderNext" function, name it "FlexSliderPrev", then make the function move the other way... The images are sliding, but showing the next image, not the previous one. How can I fix this? I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: I would start by renaming your first object to `FlexSlider` and just adding `changeOrderPrev()` and `gotoPrev()` to that as another function. Then in `addEvents`, add your "prev" event listeners. Then you can remove the second object altogether to simplify things.

Comment: `if(this.current == this.num_items)` in "next" is checking if you're already at the end of the list. You want the opposite functionality for "prev", so change the logic to `if(this.current == 1) this.current = this.num_items;` i.e if it's already at the beginning, go to the end

Comment: I think the "prev" `for` loops can be the same as the "next" loops. `for(let i=this.current; i<=this.num_items; i++) {` and `for(let i=1; i<this.current; i++) {`. If you want more help, please make this a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include your HTML so we can actually run this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled the example HTML from the link in your question, and made the changes from my comments to add "prev" functionality. The other change was adding a class variable to keep track of which direction it's transitioning (`this.direction = 'next';`) so the `transitioned` event listener knows which function to call.

```js
const FlexSlider = {
  // total no of items
  num_items: document.querySelectorAll(".slider-item").length,

  // position of current item in view
  current: 1,

  direction: '',

  init: function() {
    // set CSS order of each item initially
    document.querySelectorAll(".slider-item").forEach(function(element, index) {
      element.style.order = index + 1;
    });

    this.addEvents();
  },

  addEvents: function() {
    var that = this;

    // click on next item button
    document.querySelector("#next-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.direction = 'next';
      this.gotoNext();
    });

    // click on prev item button
    document.querySelector("#prev-button").addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.direction = 'prev';
      this.gotoPrev();
    });

    // after each item slides in, slider container fires transitionend event
    document.querySelector("#slider-container-outer").addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      if (this.direction == 'next') {
        this.changeOrderNext();
      } else {
        this.changeOrderPrev();
      }
    });
  },

  changeOrderNext: function() {
    // change current position
    if (this.current == this.num_items)
      this.current = 1;
    else
      this.current++;

    let order = 1;

    // change order from current position till last
    for (let i = this.current; i <= this.num_items; i++) {
      document.querySelector(".slider-item[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
      order++;
    }

    // change order from first position till current
    for (let i = 1; i < this.current; i++) {
      document.querySelector(".slider-item[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
      order++;
    }

    // translate back to 0 from -100%
    // we don't need transitionend to fire for this translation, so remove transition CSS
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").classList.remove('slider-container-transition');
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
  },

  gotoNext: function() {
    // translate from 0 to -100% 
    // we need transitionend to fire for this translation, so add transition CSS
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").classList.add('slider-container-transition');
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").style.transform = 'translateX(-100%)';
  },

  changeOrderPrev: function() {
    // change current position
    if (this.current == 1)
      this.current = this.num_items;
    else
      this.current--;

    let order = 1;

    // change order from current position till last
    for (let i = this.current; i <= this.num_items; i++) {
      document.querySelector(".slider-item[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
      order++;
    }

    // change order from first position till current
    for (let i = 1; i < this.current; i++) {
      document.querySelector(".slider-item[data-position='" + i + "']").style.order = order;
      order++;
    }

    // translate back to 0 from -100%
    // we don't need transitionend to fire for this translation, so remove transition CSS
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").classList.remove('slider-container-transition');
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
  },

  gotoPrev: function() {
    // translate from 0 to -100% 
    // we need transitionend to fire for this translation, so add transition CSS
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").classList.add('slider-container-transition');
    document.querySelector("#slider-container").style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
  }
};

FlexSlider.init();
```

```css
#slider-container-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}


/* CSS transition applied when translation of items happen */

.slider-container-transition {
  transition: transform 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.slider-item {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-container-outer">
  <div id="slider-container" class="slider-container-transition">
    <div class="slider-item" data-position="1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="slider-item" data-position="2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="slider-item" data-position="3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="slider-item" data-position="4">Item 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="prev-button">Prev Item</button>
<button id="next-button">Next Item</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much—this worked! But then it seems there's a conflict when I add multiple duplicates of this carousel on one page. should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: Sure? But the issue is likely that IDs should be unique per page. A better approach would be to modify everything (HTML/JS/CSS) to use classes instead of IDs so it's more reusable. I.e. add another wrapper around your current HTML, anf then changr all IDs to classes. Then you can adjust the click listeners on the buttons to find the parent element first, and select the `.slider-container-outer` (or whatever child element) from there